# How to do load test in gatling with timers?

Tags: performance-testing, gatling

I am newbie to the Gatling load test tool. I want to use the Timers(ex. Gaussian random timer, Uniform random timer) in the scenario like JMeter Timers. Is any way to use it?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [pause method](http://gatling.io/docs/current/general/scenario/#scenario-pause). Out of the box it offers fixed and uniform random pauses. But you can also assign your own expressions to get the effect you're looking for.

See this example from [the docs](http://gatling.io/docs/current/general/concepts/#scenario):

```
scenario("Standard User")
  .exec(http("Access Github").get("https://github.com"))
  .pause(2, 3) //uniform random pause
  .exec(http("Search for 'gatling'").get("https://github.com/search?q=gatling"))
  .pause(2) //fixed pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the quick cheat sheet: http://gatling.io/docs/current/cheat-sheet/. The stuff you're looking for is in the Base 
Structures section.

`pause` is the most basic option. It just pauses the simulation for the time period. However there are more advanced ones like `pace` and `rendezvous` which are a bit more sophisticated.